# Maximum sub array modulo using Kadane algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve hackerrank problem - Maximum sub array modulo - described here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-subarray-sum/problem.
I am curious if this problem can be solved with Kadane algorithm.

The goal: given an n-element array of integers, and an integer 'm' , determine the maximum value of the sum of any of its subarrays modulo 'm'.

Input Format:

1) First line contains an integer 'q' denoting the number of queries to perform. Each query is described over two lines:

a) The first line contains two space-separated integers
  describing  - array length and  modulo number.

b) The second line contains  space-separated integers describing the 
   elements of array.

Here is the likely C++ code that I came up . It fails for some of the test cases (sorry the test cases are too large to post here). Could you comment/review as why this may not work? Thanks.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    uint64_t q = 0, n = 0, m = 0;

    std::cin >> q;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin >> m;

    while(q) {
        std::vector<uint64_t> vec;
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            uint64_t num;
            std::cin >> num;
            vec.push_back(num);
        }
        uint64_t subArrayMax = 0;
        uint64_t maxMod = 0;
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // Kadane's algorithm.
            subArrayMax = std::max(subArrayMax, subArrayMax+vec[i]); // try (a+b)%m=(a%m+b%m)%m trick?
            maxMod = std::max(maxMod, subArrayMax % m);
        }
        std::cout << maxMod;
        --q;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sub array needs to be contiguous?

Comment: Try to find a small example where your algorithm fails. Than come back with the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kadane's algorithm is not working here because it involves property of modular arithmetic.

First you have to understand why Kadane's algorithm works: It is a simple dynamic programming which answers the following question:

> If we know the maximum sum end at index **i-1**, then maximum sum end at **i** is either append `a[i]` to the subarray yielding answer at **i-1**, OR not appending it

With modular arithmetic, this does not work. For eg:

`Let A = {1,2,3,4}, M = 6`

With Kadane's algorithm, of course, maximum sum is adding all elements, and it can be found using the thought quoted above: Keep appending `a[i]` into previous maximum sum found.

But if we are finding ***maximum sum % 6***, then answer is (2+3)%6 = 5 but not (1+2+3)%6 = 0 or (1+2+3+4)%6 = 4. The larger the ***maximum sum*** **NOT IMPLIES** a more optimal sum for ***maximum sum % M***. Therefore your goal here is not even finding ***maximum sum***.

---

This problem can be solved in `O(N lg N)` using a modified version of Kadane's algorithm.

For a specific index **i**,

Let `DP(i)` = maximum subarray sum % M end at i

Let `PS(i)` be the **prefix sum % M** end at **i**

Naturally you will start to think how to find some `j < i` which `(PS(i) - PS(j)+ M) % M` is maximum. (Assume you know how to precompute `PS` and basic modular arithmetic)

---

Here is the core part: turns out

> **DP(i) = max(PS(i),  (PS(i) - PS(j) + M) % M**
>
> Where **PS(j')** is the ***smallest number larger*** than **PS(i)** out of all `j < i`

Why? Because look at the formula, if `PS(j') < PS(i)`, then it is of course better **NOT TO** minus anything from `PS(i)`.

However if `PS(j') > PS(i)`, then we can rewrite the formula like this: `(M - x)%M`, then we want `x = PS(j')-PS(i)` as small as possible, so that `(M - x)%M` is the largest.

Same as Kadane's algorithm, we keep track the maximum answer found along the process.

We can use priority queue or set data structure to find such `j'` for all `i` online, achieving `O(N lg N)` in total. Details you can see below accepted code:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define LL long long
using namespace std;

int T;
set<LL> pre;
LL n, M, a[100010], ans, sum;

int main() {
    cin >> T;
    while(T--){
        ans = sum = 0;
        pre.clear();
        cin >> n >> M;
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++) cin >> a[i];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            (sum += a[i]) %= M;
            ans = max(ans, sum);
            ans = max(ans, (sum - *(pre.upper_bound(sum))+M)%M);
            pre.insert(sum);
        }
        cout << ans << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shole for the details. Understood the source of the problem now.

Comment: Attempting to access `*(pre.upper_bound(sum))` when `i=0` (empty `pre`) is undefined behaviour.